# Use seaborn to make time series plot instead of pandas.dataframe.plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the foll. dataframe:

```
df
          A         R
0    0.000000     0.000000
1  176.069152   544.511391
2  352.338584   965.989678
3  528.824516  1387.844940
4  705.510351  1809.956118
```

I can plot it like this:

```
df.plot()
```

How can I do this in seaborn? I am trying this, but it does not work. Please note that I do not want to explicitly specify column names, since the number of columns is much larger than this toy example.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.tsplot(data=df, time=df.index, value=df)
```

Comment: `df.plot()` after `import seaborn` doesn't work?

Comment: it does, how do I make tsplot work though?

Comment: Do you want something like this? `sns.tsplot(data=df.T.values, time=df.index)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33461664/seaborn-time-series-from-pandas-dataframe

Comment: thanks @mwaskom, and thanks for an excellent library!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood it right, my recommendation is to do it with matplotlib like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = df.index

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for name in df.columns.values:
    ax.plot(x, df[name], label=name)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]